# maximum of the function $f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1 } \sin n x /n^\alpha $

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-series, maxima-minima

Here $\alpha >1 $. The function is defined as

$$f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1 } \sin n x /n^\alpha .$$

The domain is $(0, \pi)$.

We know that if $\alpha = 1$, $f(x) = (\pi -x )/2$.

If $\alpha >1$, the jump at $x =0 $ is softened into a boundary layer.

The function has the following picture. The question is, where is the maximum? How does it scale with $\alpha$? Is it power of $( \alpha -1 )$?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the general case, we have
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} i \left(\text{Li}_{\alpha }\left(e^{-i x}\right)-\text{Li}_{\alpha
   }\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)$$ So, for a given $\alpha$, we need to solve for $x$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{Li}_{\alpha-1}\left(e^{-i x}\right)+\text{Li}_{\alpha-1}\left(e^{i
   x}\right)\right)=0$$ which does not show analytical solutions.

Using numerical methods, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha& x_{\text{max}} \\
 1.5 & 0.74377 \\
 2.0 & 1.04720 \\
 2.5 & 1.21912 \\
 3.0 & 1.32779 \\
 3.5 & 1.40038 \\
 4.0 & 1.45035 \\
 4.5 & 1.48534 \\
 5.0 & 1.51007 \\
 5.5 & 1.52763 \\
 6.0 & 1.54013 \\
 6.5 & 1.54902 \\
 7.0 & 1.55534 \\
 7.5 & 1.55984 \\
 8.0 & 1.56303 \\
 8.5 & 1.56530 \\
 9.0 & 1.56690 \\
 9.5 & 1.56804 \\
 10.0 & 1.56885
\end{array}
\right)$$

I suppose that you already noticed where this is going.

Comment: I am more interested in the small $\alpha - 1 $ regime. Can one get some analytic estimate?

Comment: @Beamer. Analytic could be hard. We can do the same. What is the range of interest ?

Comment: I actually want an asymptotic formula in terms of $\alpha - 1 $ as $\alpha \rightarrow 0 $.